# How to get the intersection line between two .csv file?

Tags: regex, csv, filter, sed, spreadsheet

How to get the intersection line between two .csv file?
My question seem quite difficult to understand but i will give you an example like this:

I have 2 .csv files:

```
+---+-------+----+      +-----------------+
| A |   B   | C  |      | A  |   B   | C  |
+---+-------+----+      +----+-------+----+
| 1 | ant   | 14 |*     | 6  | Fan   | 12 |
| 2 | bird  | 11 |      | 7  | gun   | 55 |*
| 3 | cat   | 21 |*     | 8  | horse | 21 |*
| 4 | dog   | 55 |*     | 9  | ice   | 15 |
| 5 | egg   | 99 |      | 10 | jar   | 14 |*
+---+-------+---+       +----+-------+----+
     Table 1                  Table 2
```

So, if i use Table 1 to filter Table 2 i will get the output like this:

```
+----------------+
| A |   B   |  C |
+---+-------+----+     
| 7 | gun   | 55 |*     
| 8 | horse | 21 |*    
| 10| jar   | 14 |*       
+---+-------+----+     
    Table 3
```

Yes, i use the last column of Table 1 to Filter on Table 2

How can i filter it like this with any tool?

Comment: How large are your files? Could you use a Macro? Could you use MS-Access or any other RDBMs?

Comment: @EmmadKareem about hundred-thousand to million lines.

Comment: I would use a DB for such a task.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Can you ans me on answer box how to select data and export them to .csv by DB? thank you sir.

Comment: I would be happy to answer if I know the details. Now do you want to get the data inside the database from CSV? Or you want to export the data from the database to CSV file? What database do you have (Access/SQL Server/etc.)?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Basically, You just give me a sql command that can filter data following to my example that i showed you and put the result in to another Table(in example is table3) that enough. For export it to .csv i think it not so difficult. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, here is what I did:

```
Create table T1 (A INT, B VARCHAR(100), C INT);

Create table T2 (A INT, B VARCHAR(100), C INT);

Insert into T1 Values (1, 'ant',14);
Insert into T1 Values (2, 'bird',11);
Insert into T1 Values (3, 'cat',21);
Insert into T1 Values (4, 'dog',55);
Insert into T1 Values (5, 'egg',99);

Insert into T2 Values (6, 'fan',12);
Insert into T2 Values (7, 'gun',55);
Insert into T2 Values (8, 'horse',21);
Insert into T2 Values (9, 'ice',15);
Insert into T2 Values (10, 'jar',14);
```

I am not sure if you have the data already in the table or not, there are tools to import csv files into your db.

If you are going to run the query often, then building an index on column A of each table would speed up the process. I did not build any indexes for this simple case.

The select required to get your result is:

```
select * from t2,t1 where t2.c = t1.c order by t2.a
```

If you are happy with the results you can put it in a table like this (SQL Server)

```
SELECT T2.A, T2.B , T2.C INTO TEST FROM t2,t1 where t2.c = t1.c order by t2.a
```

I hope this is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input files do only contain the numbers and strings, without the additional table-formatting characters (just a `\t` separated file), you may do the following:

Table 1 (t1.txt):

```
1       ant     14
2       bird    11
3       cat     21
4       dog     55
5       egg     99
```

Table 2 (t2.txt):

```
6       Fan     12
7       gun     55
8       horse   21
9       ice     15
10      jar     14
```

And the execution and output:

```
$ join -j 3 -o '2.1,2.2,2.3' <(sort -k 3n t1.txt) <(sort -k 3n t2.txt) | sort -n
7 gun 55
8 horse 21
10 jar 14
```

Alternatively, if you have many columns, you may first extract only the *filtering column*, and later perform the selection itself. Also, you may output the `join`-input files without specifying an initial pattern (all the columns, in your case). After the execution you simply select the columns you actually want to display (using `cut`, for exampĺe):

```
$ join -2 15 <(cut -f 15 t1.txt | sort) <(sort -k 15 t2.txt) | sort -n
```

Notice `cut` uses `\t` as the default separator -- which can be redefined with flag `-d <separator>`. Anyway, as pointed by @EmmadKareem, you may be better off using a proper DB for this task -- as it will have dozens of optimizations, surely required by your hundred-thousand/million lines.

Comment: +1.  Note that it is trivial to put the input files into the desired format and can be done at the same time as the sort.  If the join will be done more than once, it makes sense to pre-process only once.

Comment: @Rubens Can you show me a command for 18 columns table and use 15th column to filter.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+\s?){3}/\/(^\\S+\\s){2}\1$\/p/' file1.csv | sed -nrf - file2.csv
```

for a file that is space or tab separated.

For a file that is comma separated:

```
sed -r 's/([^,]+,?){3}/\/(^[^,]+,){2}\1$\/p/' file1.csv | sed -nrf - file2.csv
```

This works by creating a sed script from the first table and then uses it to filter against the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script in **Perl** to do the job you want.

It works by scanning the first file and keeping the values of the third column in memory. Then it scans the second file and for every line read it compares the value of the third column  with those in memory, if there is a match, it prints the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

my %seen;

open my $file1_fh, '<', 'file1.txt' 
    or die "Can't open file1.txt $!";

while (<$file1_fh>) {
    chomp;
    $seen{ (split)[2] } = 1; #assumes line are delimited by whitespace.
}

close $file1_fh;

open my $file2_fh, '<', 'file2.txt'
    or die "Can't open file2.txt $!";


while (<$file2_fh>) {
    chomp;
    my $third_column_value = (split)[2]; #assumes line are delimited by whitespace.
    say if $seen{ $third_column_value };
}

close $file2_fh;

__END__

#OUTPUT
7 gun 55
8 horse 21
10 jar 14
```